# Principles to create natural data for a clustering algorithm?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, random-generation

I have come up with an algorithm to cluster geospatial data points. I have quite a few volunteers (100) collecting data for me, using my app on their smart phones to check in at places. However, I'm afraid the data will be positively biased since the volunteers all receive instructions on how to use the app. The data will just be too perfect and easy for my algorithm. So, I intend to ask some to deliberately create noisy data (by checking in at wrong positions). My questions are:

- Is asking people to create wrong data a sound way?
- If so, what is the optimal percentage of such data? Say, 20 out of 100?

Better yet, can you point me to some good research papers on **principles** of creating effective data? I.e, the data that best replicates real-world situations.

Comment: Here's a couple of links: http://www.causality.inf.ethz.ch/data/dataset_generation.html http://www.quora.com/Machine-Learning/What-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-training-set-for-machine-learning The answer is that you _can't_ make a realistic set, so just do the best you can with what you got.

Comment: Just curious: what's the problem with too-perfect data? Are you anticipating worse data from non-volunteer future users and hoping to make your algorithm more robust against bad input?

Comment: @NickStauner yes

Comment: I don't think you can really "make" a natural data set this way, pretty much by definition. In fact, your aplication will likely change over time, your userbase *will* change, and thus your data characteristics will be changing. You need to be prepared to frequently adapt your process to changes in the data, or build it in a way such that it tries to automatically adapt.